# understanding Activity's setContentView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I need to create all the UI programmatically "on demand", this means I can't use any XML. This is the pseudo code of what I do:

```
View v = new MyView();
activity.setContentView(v);

tabHost = new TabHost();
....
tabHost.setup();
TabSpec tabSpec = _tabHost.newTabSpec(page);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(title);
        tabSpec.setContent((TabContentFactory) this);

activity.setContentView(tabHost);
```

so when TabContentFactory is called I return the view which is the content view of the current activity. Basically what I do is taking current view and wrapping it in the tabhost.
It half works, when I do this I'm able to see the tabbar, but only black view below it, if I click on other tab and then click back then I can see the view, everything works as intended.
**Now why I think it's related to `setContentView`, because when I do this:**

```
   View v = new MyView();
//    activity.setContentView(v); // we don't use it as current content view


tabHost = new TabHost();
....
tabHost.setup();
TabSpec tabSpec = _tabHost.newTabSpec(page);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(title);
        tabSpec.setContent((TabContentFactory) this);
```

Then everything is working perfectly.
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, I found what was wrong, when `setContentView` is called then the view attaches to the parent and that's why it does not appear in the tabhost. To remove the view from it's parent this code can be used:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)(myView.getParent());
vg.removeView(myView);
```